Power Supply Double Output +12 V -12 V
I’m checking this power supply.
But it works to supply the diagram I attach?
The situation is because I see in the diagram is required -12 V and +12 V, then I don’t know exactly: if what I need is from that power supply connect the -V output to the -12 V Pin10 and the +12 V to the Pin 9 and done? Means in the diagram the DC Common the -12 V outputs of the power supply? Or I need a double-output power supply or two power supplies, to generate two different outputs, one the -12 V and the other to generate the +12 V?

coerrace - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. TY

A single power supply outputs +12V in respect to the DC common selected as 0V ground reference.
A dual power supply outputs +12V and -12V in respect to the DC common selected as 0V ground reference.
That circuit cannot work with a single supply output, it needs a dual supply.
So the 12V 5A supply will not work, plus it has dangerously exposed mains input for beginner hobbyist projects.

Oh I see. What power supply can I purchase as example? I want to do is run an old device that captured data in video tapes and restored to files in Commodore Amiga. This is the scehmatic of the serial port in Amiga. However as I don’t have an amiga just the decide I will use a serial to USB converter but I need to power supply as the device requires the 12V and -12V. https://wiki.amigaos.net/wiki/Advanced_Serial_Debugging_Guide

Pin 9 and 10 are the voltages and are used by the device to capture the information from the video tapes. I will run in a PC the USB serial converter.

@coerrace Thanks for explaining what the circuit is used for - video tapes recorded with data patterns as video output from an Amiga. Well you could just buy two power supplies, but not those you mentioned for the reasons they are dangerous and 5A current available is a lot more if you need max 0.1A. Maybe buy two cheap 12V linear wall warts, the switch mode wall warts may be too noisy. In a pinch, two 9V batteries may work.

What are you trying to do? That 24V circuit (+/- 12V) will work with a 12V single sided supply (+12,-0), and will run output up to close to the rails (+12V,-0), because that op amp is a "rail to rail" op amp, and works down to 7V (+7,-0).
If you actually need a (+12V to -12V) output signal, a (+12,0) supply won't be satisfactory. If you actually need to have [GND] halfway between [+ and -], then a single-sided supply won't be satisfactory.
If all you really need on the output is +/-5V, single sided, then a 12V single-sided supply is good enough.

"That 24V circuit (+/- 12V) will work with a 12V single sided supply (+12,-0),"  --  Disagree.  Because the circuit as shown is DC coupled throughout, it cannot work with a single supply without modifications.  The circuit is designed to create an output that swings both above and below GND.  That cannot happen without a negative voltage rail.

What power supply can I purchase for this is not required a lot of Amperes. Is to use to emulate a serial port but yes is an old device cable to convert data from video through serial port in Amiga port. As I don’t have Amiga I will us a rs232 cable but the old deivce requires to be fed with that 2 voltages then

@AnalogKid I haven't changed my answer because it already addresses your objection: If all you need is 5V single sided, then 12V single sided is good enough. The input appears to be single sided: the requirement for double sided 12V output for serial is historical and may not be required by the OP.
